# Which homotheties preserve the lattice?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose two lattices $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z}\omega_1 + \mathbb{Z}\omega_2$ and $\Lambda' = \tau \Lambda = \mathbb{Z}\tau \omega_1 + \mathbb{Z}\tau \omega_2$ are homothetic. Under what conditions are these two lattices equal as sets? I know that we can express $\tau \omega_1 = a\omega_1 + b\omega_2$ and $\tau \omega_2 = c\omega_1 + d\omega_2$ where $ad-bc = 1$ and $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$. But what are all the values of $\tau$ that preserve the lattice?

Comment: You may as well assume your lattice is generated by $1$ and a complex number $\omega$ with positive imaginary part. (With a bit more work, you can also assume without loss of generality that $|\Re \omega| \leq 1/2$ and $|\omega| \geq 1$.) Now, there are (finitely many) values of $\tau$ that preserve an arbitrary lattice, and there are (finitely many) choices of $\omega$ for which _additional_ values of $\tau$ preserve the lattice. These "exceptional" lattices are geometrically nice (i.e., once you find them, it will be obvious), and they're not difficult to discover algebraically.

Comment: Basically, $\tau = \pm 1$ always works (evidently), and for some lattices $\tau = \pm i$, and for some $\tau = e^{2\pi ik/3}$.